# Which foreign keys do I use if they are repeated

Tags: mysql, schema, foreign-key, rdbms

I have the following two tables

company_relationships

```
|ID|Company_ID|Affiliate_ID|<Relationship Info>|
+--+----------+------------+-------------------+
```

jobs

```
|ID|Company_ID|<Job Info>|
+--+----------+----------+
```

and I need to keep a record of job offers (i.e. a company offers a job to its affiliate). Do I use:
job_offers

```
|ID|Job_ID|CompanyRelationship_ID|<Offer Info>|
+--+------+----------------------+------------+
```

or

```
|ID|Job_ID|Affiliate_ID|<Offer Info>|
+--+------+------------+------------+
```

or something else?

I want to use the first one, because relationship info applies to the job offer, but then Company_ID is specified by both Job_ID and CompanyRelationship_ID. Is there an issue with this / better schema to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you go for the Option 1, how do you Identify the Affiliate?
and that's why I think Option 2 is better, unless I am missing something

Comment: The affiliate is specified by the CompanyRelationship, as well as whatever configurations are specified for that relationship